# Courses in moodle API

Tags: moodle

Get enrolled courses of a user:
        $mcourses = enroll_get_my_courses();

```
    $mycourses = new html_table();
    $mycourses->head = array('userid', 'mycourses');
    $mycourses->attributes['class'] = 'tabler';

    foreach ($mcourses as $all) {
        $mycourses->data[] = new html_table_row(array(implode(array($all->userid)), $all->fullname));                                                                                 
    }
```

Get all courses in the moodle system:

```
$syscourses = enrol_get_all_users_courses();

    $allcourses = new html_table();
    $allcourses->head = array('allcourses');
    $allcourses->attributes['class'] = 'tabler';

    foreach ($syscourses as $sys) {
         $allcourses->data[] = new html_table_row(array(implode(array($all->fullname)));                                                                                  
    }
```

Comment: What do you actually want to show? Get student's enroled courses?

Comment: Both. For admin, I want to show all courses and for users, enrolled courses.

Answer (score 0):

To get all courses of a particular user:

```
$mycourses = enrol_get_my_courses();
```

The word is "enrol" with a single "L" not two Ls

To get all the courses you have to use

```
$courses = get_courses();
```

Comment: Thank You Tafhim. I couldn't extract them into values for the function enrol_get_my_courses();

Comment: Can you elaborate more? The function should return list of all courses the current signed in user is in.

Comment: I could extract the course names from get_courses(); like $a = get_courses();
    foreach ($a as $all) {
        $table->data[] = new html_table_row(array(implode(array($all->fullname))));                                                                                 
    }

Comment: Similarly I want to make work for enrol_get_my_courses();

Comment: Yes because it returns as an array of courses so print out the result and you will know how to get the course full name,

Comment: Yes, I got your words. I was asking, how could I retrieve the values of  enrol_get_my_courses() ? I